# New Discord Username System

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

so currently i have this python bot that when a user tries to store something the author name along with the discriminator('#') is stored as well

`return "**Hello** **" + message.author.name + "#" + message.author.discriminator + "** ** :wave: "`

so my question is when they remove the discriminator
and apply the new username system, how can i change that in my bot that it stores the username? also am i going to need to upgrade my discord python package and will they add something like this?
`message.author.username`
because when i currently try to call `message.author.username` i get this

```
'User' object has no attribute 'username`
```

Comment: @JoachimSauer sorry its my first question so i didn't know i can format ♥

Comment: No worries, it's much more readable now, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Discord.py package will be updated sometime after discord applies the username system.

For now, you can't use the new system as the developers of Discord.py need to see how the new system works before they implement changes.

**As for your question**:

You will have to update the Discord.py package when an update eventually comes out, otherwise you will not be able to use the updated methods. We also don't know how storing the username will be executed, but `message.author.username` seems like a good guess of what the method will be like

Comment: thanks for the answer but is there's a way i can keep track of when the changes are implemented to update my bot? like how will i know the package was updated?

Comment: They will probably notify everyone on [their official discord](https://discord.com/invite/r3sSKJJ)

Answer (score 0):

Today, the discord.py update that was talked about here was just released!

If you want to update, just use `python -m pip install -U discord.py` in your venv (if any)

Here is the [changelog](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whats_new.html#v2-3-0)